# How to make div section of code slideshow WebMatrix

Tags: slideshow, webmatrix

I am a new user to WebMatrix.  In using the Bakery template, they have a section of code called their featuredProduct that will randomly display a product in this section with each page load.  How can I make it do a 'slideshow' for this block of code?  For example, I would like it to Randomly display one of the x number of products.  Display the production, description, and Request More Information box for a certain number of seconds, then display one of the other products?

Thanks in advance.

```
    <div id="featuredProduct">
       <a href="~/Images/Products/@featured.ImageName" data-     lightbox="~/Images/Products/@featured.ImageName">
       <img alt="Featured Product" src="~/Images/Products/@featured.ImageName"/>
       </a>
    <div id="featuredProductInfo">
    <div id="productInfo">
        <h2>@featured.Name</h2>
        <p class="price">$@string.Format("{0:f}", featured.Price)</p>
        <p class="description">@featured.Description</p>
    </div>
    <div id="callToAction">
        <a class="order-button" href="~/order/@featured.Id" title="Order @featured.Name">Request More Information</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this old post of mine: [An enhanced WebMatrix Bakery template](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/499466/An-enhanced-WebMatrix-Bakery-template).

It should still work.